# What does Rugor Nass' dialog mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Rugor Nass: **Yousa cannot bees hair. Dis army of Mackineeks up dare is
> new weesong.**
>
> Jinn: A droid army is about to attack the Naboo. We must warn them.

What does Boss Nass' dialog mean?

Comment: *"You cannot be here. This army of mechanicals up there..."* seems pretty straightforward without any need for translation. It's only the last bit that's a bother.

Comment: I got it as: "You cannot beat them. This army of machines up there is a new weapon". Meaning a new weapon against which they have no hope of winning.

Comment: http://www.talklikejarjarday.com/blog/135-the-meaning-of-the-word-weesong"... *is no reason* [for you to be here]>

Comment: ***You cannot be here. This army of mechanicals up there is no reason.***

Comment: Interestingly, the line in the official novelisation is *"“Yous can’t be here. Dis army of maccaneks up dere **tis not our problem.”*"**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So most of it is fairly obvious to a native english-speaker:

> "[Yousa](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) cannot bees hair. Dis army of mackineeks up dare tis new
> weesong!"

becomes

> You cannot be here.  The army of *Mackineeks* on the planetary surface is *new weesong*.

"Mackineeks" is clearly a play on the world "mechanics" and is an obvious reference to the Trade Federation's Droid Army.  The only real question (and indeed Lucasfilm has never officially given a meaning) is what "new weesong" means.  Personally I think it means "no reason" given the context and the abominable madness that is Gungan Basic.  Which gives us this:

> You cannot be here.  The army of Droids on the planetary surface is no reason.

That second sentence is still grammatically stilted/awkward, but in essence means

> "A Droid army invading the planet is not a reason for you to be here."

So you can read the sentences combined as:

> **You cannot be here, and a droid army on the surface is not a valid excuse for you to be here.**

Again, Lucasfilm has not (to my knowledge) given an official translation, but given the rest of the dialog it makes sense in context.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the translation should be:

"You cannot be here.  This army of machines up there is no reason."

Plainly, at this point Nass does not understand that the machines are going to attack the Naboo.  Possibly he believes that they actually *belong* to the Naboo.

Comment: I believe he's well aware that the surface has been invaded and that an attack (on the Naboo) is imminent. He just doesn't think that it's a problem for the Gungans, and seems to blame the Naboo for bringing it on themselves.